# Select statement with inner join

Tags: mysql, sql, select, inner-join

```
Table A                      Table B
ID     Name                  ID     Name    Last_Name
1      John                  1      John    Depp
2      Henry                 2      David   Henry
3      Ken
```

I was try to select the name in a statement with these condition:

1. If the `NAME` in `TableA` able to map with the `NAME` in `TableB`, then choose the `Last_Name`
2. If the `NAME` is `TableA` is equal to `LAST_NAME` in `TableB`, then select the `NAME` from `TableA`
3. If the `NAME` in `TableA` not able to map with `TableB`'s `NAME` or `LAST_NAME`, then select `NAME` from `TableA`.

Method i used:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT A.ID NO, LAST_NAME REALNAME
 FROM TABLEA A
 INNER JOIN TABLEB B
 ON A.NAME = B.NAME
    UNION ALL
 SELECT A.ID NO, A.NAME REALNAME
 FROM TABLEA A
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TABLEB B WHERE A.NAME = B.LAST_NAME)
    UNION ALL
 SELECT A.ID NO, A.NAME REALNAME
 FROM TABLEA A
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TABLEB B WHERE A.NAME = B.NAME OR A.NAME = B.LAST_NAME)
)AS T
```

**QUESTION:** Is that any more simplify query i can use to achieve the conditions?

Comment: Are the IDs between the two reliably related?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use CASE TO make more readable

```
SELECT A.ID NO, CASE WHEN A.Name = B.Name THEN B.LAST_NAME 
                     WHEN A.Name = B.LAST_NAME THEN A.NAME 
                     WHEN A.Name = B.Name AND A.Name = B.LAST_NAME THEN A.NAME  END AS REALNAME
FROM TABLEA A, TABLEB B
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use inner and outer joins rather than your exists and not exists subqueries, which may perform better:

```
select a.id, b.last_name as realname
  from tablea a
  join tableb b
    on a.name = b.name
union all
select distinct a.id, a.name
  from tablea a
  join tableb b
    on a.name = b.last_name
union all
select a.id, a.name
  from tablea a
  left join tableb b
    on a.name = b.name
    or a.name = b.last_name
 where b.name is null
```

Comment: Note that if `last_name` is not unique in `tableb`, the second `SELECT` in this statement can return *more* rows than the original query does.

Comment: @spencer7593 true, so I just added a distinct to address that

Comment: @BrianDeMilla: the addition of the `DISTINCT` keyword should resolve that nicely, as long as `(id,name)` tuple is unique in TABLEA. (The normative pattern is for a unique constraint on `id`, and the sample data doesn't show any duplicates. We note that we haven't been given an explicit guarantee that `(id,name)` is unique.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can make your statement "clearer" by formatting it. It's also clearer for the human reader if you avoid re-using the same table alias (also makes the EXPLAIN output easier to correlate to the statemnt). ALso, if you use lowercase for the table aliases and column names, and qualify ALL column references. Also, eliminating the unnecessary inline view would also make the statement easier to read.

This is functionally equivalent to your original statement, but it is "clearer"

```
    SELECT a.id        AS `NO`
         , b.last_name AS `REALNAME`
      FROM TABLEA a
      JOIN TABLEB b
        ON a.name = b.name
     UNION ALL
    SELECT e.id        AS `NO`
         , e.name      AS `REALNAME`
      FROM TABLEA e
     WHERE EXISTS 
           (SELECT 1 FROM TABLEB f WHERE f.last_name = e.name)
     UNION ALL
    SELECT o.id        AS `NO`
         , o.name      AS `REALNAME`
      FROM TABLEA o
     WHERE NOT EXISTS 
           (SELECT 1 FROM TABLEB p WHERE o.name IN (p.name,p.last_name))
```

(I'd also prefer lowercase for the tablenames; but your system may be setup to use case-sensitive table names. It would also be clearer if the names of the tables were less ambiguous.)

The `NOT EXISTS` predicate in the last SELECT could be replaced with an anti-join pattern; as to whether that would be "clearer"... for those familiar with the anti-join pattern and the ability to pick it out, it might be. To the uninitiated, probably not, and the `NOT EXISTS` is clearer.)